# File.Exists throws System.IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, file

This one is odd.

Whenever trying to access a file in a certain area of my program (Nested in an if determining if the file exists), it throws a `System.IndexOutOfRangeException`. `File.Exists` isn't even supposed to throw that! Here's my script.

```
if (Directory.Exists("SA_Data") && File.Exists("SA_Data/stock_names.txt"))
{
    Array.Clear(Globals.stocks, 0, Globals.stocks.Length);
    Globals.stocks[1] = "empty";

    // **********************************************
    // This should return true. It raises an exception
    bool whatever = File.Exists("SA_Data/stock_names.txt");
    // **********************************************

    // I get the same exception in File.ReadAllLines, below
    foreach (string stock in File.ReadAllLines("SA_Data/stock_names.txt"))
    {
        MessageBox.Show(stock);
        if(Globals.stocks[1] != "empty")
        {
            Array.Resize(ref Globals.stocks, Globals.stocks.Length);
            Globals.stocks[Globals.stocks.Length - 1] = stock;
        }
        else
        {
            Globals.stocks[0] = stock;
        }
    }
}
```

The file exists, is not empty, is not open and has proper permissions to be opened. What's going on?

Thanks,
-Dylan

Comment: Where you do get that error thrown?

Comment: where is the file located? The path doesn't seem to be correct.For one use the fully qualified path.File.Exists(@"c:\SA_data\stock_names.txt").Also you are using forward slash?

Comment: I dont see any reason that can create indexOutOfRangeException, it will return false if path contains any invalid character (so path can't be issue). @AlgoRythm can you try re-executing your code without any array "Globals.stocks[1]"

Comment: @inquisitive_mind, the backslash gives a compiler error (Unrecognized escape sequence), and the file is relative of the source program.

Comment: @HardikPanchal Commenting out everything to do with the Globals.stocks array worked! How curious it would throw the exception at the file reading command. Anyways, Fantastic, and thank you :)

Comment: so their might be issue with your Global.stocks (probably you have declared lower sized array). and not sure why it is giving exception on next line.

Comment: you must specify the complete path

Comment: Are you sure you haven't compiled this in release mode? The documentation about the method does not mention index out of range exception, and I find it hard to believe *that line* is what's causing it. It's likely another line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array resizing is just not the sort of thing you should do in general. So, here is what I would propose instead:

```
if (Directory.Exists("SA_Data") && File.Exists("SA_Data/stock_names.txt"))
{
    var stocks = new List<string>();

    foreach (string stock in File.ReadAllLines("SA_Data/stock_names.txt"))
    {
        MessageBox.Show(stock);
        stocks.Add(stock);
    }
    Global.stocks = stocks.ToArray();
}
```